# Spring: Using @Qualifier with Annoation based Spring Configuration

Tags: java, spring, annotations

How to use @Qualifier with annotation-based spring configuration?

Samples I've seen used xml-based which requires id attribute

Thank you in advance

EDIT:

I'm sorry if my question above was unclear. Here's my attempt to use @Qualifier+annotation-based configuration

```
@Bean(name="explorerTableList")
ObservableList<ExplorerTableAdapter> explorerTableList() {
    return FXCollections.observableArrayList();
}
```

In my constructor...

```
@Autowired
public ExplorerTableGlassImpl(

    @Qualifier("explorerTableList")
    ObservableList<ExplorerTableAdapter> list

) {

    super( ExplorerTableAdapter.class, list );
}
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application init method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$156(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'facilitiesExplorerFormImpl': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'explorerTableGlassImpl' defined in file [D:\git\chartstream\ChartStream3-Facilities\target\classes\com\hccs\chartstream\facilities\x\explorertable\ExplorerTableGlassImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [javafx.collections.ObservableList]: : No qualifying bean of type [com.hccs.chartstream.facilities.x.explorertable.ExplorerTableAdapter] found for dependency [collection of com.hccs.chartstream.facilities.x.explorertable.ExplorerTableAdapter]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=explorerTableList)}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.hccs.chartstream.facilities.x.explorertable.ExplorerTableAdapter] found for dependency [collection of com.hccs.chartstream.facilities.x.explorertable.ExplorerTableAdapter]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=explorerTableList)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:84)
    at com.hccs.chartstream.facilities.ModuleContext.initialize(ModuleContext.java:23)
    at com.hccs.chartstream.facilities.FacilitiesInit.init(FacilitiesInit.java:20)
    at com.hccs.platform.PlatformApplication.lambda$0(PlatformApplication.java:57)
    at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at com.hccs.platform.PlatformApplication.initializeModules(PlatformApplication.java:55)
    at com.hccs.platform.PlatformApplication.init(PlatformApplication.java:43)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'explorerTableGlassImpl' defined in file [D:\git\chartstream\ChartStream3-Facilities\target\classes\com\hccs\chartstream\facilities\x\explorertable\ExplorerTableGlassImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [javafx.collections.ObservableList]: : No qualifying bean of type [com.hccs.chartstream.facilities.x.explorertable.ExplorerTableAdapter] found for dependency [collection of com.hccs.chartstream.facilities.x.explorertable.ExplorerTableAdapter]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=explorerTableList)}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.hccs.chartstream.facilities.x.explorertable.ExplorerTableAdapter] found for dependency [collection of com.hccs.chartstream.facilities.x.explorertable.ExplorerTableAdapter]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=explorerTableList)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:747)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1114)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1017)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:84)
    at com.hccs.chartstream.core.ui.base.classes.FormBase.setupContext(FormBase.java:48)
    at com.hccs.chartstream.core.ui.base.classes.FormBase.init(FormBase.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:133)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.hccs.chartstream.facilities.x.explorertable.ExplorerTableAdapter] found for dependency [collection of com.hccs.chartstream.facilities.x.explorertable.ExplorerTableAdapter]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=explorerTableList)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1103)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:915)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:811)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:739)
    ... 43 more
```

Comment: Google gave me this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_qualifier_annotation.htm

Comment: which uses xml-based configuration

Comment: @Zek It looks to me like you are using `@Qualifier` correctly in conjunction with `@Bean` and its `name` property, but its a bit hard to say for certain because your code snippets are incomplete. Additionally I don't see the bean definition for `explorerTableGlassImpl`

Comment: Thank you @HairOfTheDog! I created a test project which used constructor auto-wiring. You were right that I'm using the right syntax. I'll investigate my project more.